# Linux: How to modify shared library name in Dynamic Section of an ELF binary

Tags: c, linux

I have a shared library with soname: `libfoo.so`

How do I link my binary to libfoo.so such that the shared library name in my binary's ELF section is: libfoo5.so?

I tried creating a symlink: libfoo5.so -> libfoo.so, and then linking my library as such:

`g++ ... -o mybinary *.o -Lpath -lfoo5`

However, when I print out the dynamic section in my ELF binary, it reads:

`readelf -d mybinary`

I still get:

`Shared library: [libfoo.so]`

Comment: well could be platform dependent though. I am trying on an ARM cross compiler. I am seeing that the linker doesnt follow symlinks. readelf -d is giving me the libfoo5.so as a dependency and not libfoo.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually do it when building the shared library. There is a linker option called "soname" that sets it.

I don't know off-hand if you can edit it after the build, but if its possible it is probably included in the package called "elfutils". That package contains several programs designed to manipulate ELF object files.

Answer (score 1):

The file `libfoo5.so` is probably a *symlink* to actual `libfoo.so` or something of that sort. What does `ldd` say about your binary?

Comment: libfoo5.so is a symlink to libfoo.so

ldd report mybinary depends on libfoo.so

Comment: I thought the compile-time linker doesn't follow symlinks and will associate the binary with libfoo5

Comment: Recursing ... what's the `SONAME` from `readelf -d libfoo5.so`?